# Put the data from a .wav file into the flash memory of pic18F4550

Tags: audio, wav, microcontroller, pic, pic18

I'm new at hardware programming: I work with the pic18F4550 with the C compiler from microchip version 8.63. My question is: has someone example code to write a .wav file (binary data) to the flash memory of the pic18F4550?

Comment: At runtime over some interface, or at build time?

Comment: at build time I think. What's the difference?

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [bin2c](http://www.google.com/search?q=bin2c) program to convert the WAV file to a C source file with the data contained in a `const char` array. Then compile and link this file with your source code. Your linker should place `const` variables in flash memory on the PIC.

Comment: OK, can I put this array, as a global variable in my own C program on my pic18F4550?